# SQL Iterate through Results to check constraints

Tags: sql

I'm completely new to SQL or even Databases in general, so I'm not sure if this is a SQL-specific problem, but anyway here is what I have:

3 Tables:

Project

```
pid
...
finished
```

Project_Actions

```
pid
aid
```

Actions

```
aid
...
finished
```

In Case it is a needed Information:

```
pid = project ID
aid = action ID
One action can belong to >=0 projects
```

Now, I want to set the projects in the project table where all corresponding actions have been finished to finished.

The problem i'm having is that I have absolutely no Idea, how i can check ALL actions before actually Updating an Entry.
Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your table syntax is not clear. Can you try to use common syntax to describe the schema?

Comment: My question was answered already, but would you mind linking me somewhere where I can read up on Common Syntax? JIC i ever have another question :)

Comment: I guess I simply didn't understand you, but obviously others did... Perhaps you simply meant `...` to be "Other irrelevant columns". I thought the was a title line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the `pid`s that are finished like this

```
select p.pid
from projects p
join project_actions pa on pa.pid = p.pid
join actions a on pa.pid = a.pid
group by p.pid
having sum(case when p.finished = 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

If you want to update the table you can use a query like

```
update projects
set some_column = 'some value'
where pid in
(
   select p.pid
   from projects p
   join project_actions pa on pa.pid = p.pid
   join actions a on pa.pid = a.pid
   group by p.pid
   having sum(case when p.finished = 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
)
```

In MySQL you can't update the same table you are selecting from. So you need a temp table like this

```
update projects
set some_column = 'some value'
where pid in
(
   select * from 
   (
     select p.pid
     from projects p
     join project_actions pa on pa.pid = p.pid
     join actions a on pa.pid = a.pid
     group by p.pid
     having sum(case when p.finished = 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
   ) tmp
)
```

Comment: Thank you! There was only one little line I had to change, which was    
    
join actions a on pa.pid = a.pid     
to     
join actions a on pa.aid = a,aid   

Thanks again, I didn't think that "sum" would be exactly what i needed.

Comment: just saw the rest of your code, there is one problem: This query throws an Error saying that I can't specify target table Projects for Update in From clause.... Any Idea why?

Comment: Yes, just updated the answer. That is why it is so important to specify the DB engine you are using. ;)